# python plotly chart axis and variable

Tags: python, variables, charts, plotly, axis

I'm using plotly to display data from xlsx,
everything is working fine except I can't control the axis in the graph,
the head of the columns contains the month's name and that is what needs to be in the X-axis,
the first row contains the type of events which I need it to be in the variable of the graph,

here is the code:

```
import dash
import os
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel( "2022.xlsx",
     engine='openpyxl')

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(id='graph',
                          style={
            'height': 500,
            'width': 900,
            "display": "block",
            "margin-left": "auto",
            "margin-right": "auto",}),
    ),
    html.Div([
                html.Label(['Choose a graph:'],style={'font-weight': 'bold'}),
                dcc.RadioItems(
                    id='drop',
                    options=[
                             {'label': 'graph1', 'value': 'graph1'},
                             {'label': 'graph2', 'value': 'graph2'},
                             {'label': 'graph3', 'value': 'graph3'},
                    ],
                    value='age',
                    style={"width": "60%"}
                ),
        ])

])




@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='drop', component_property='value')]
)
def build_graph(value):
    
    if value == 'graph1':
        return px.scatter(
            df,
            x=["January" , "February" , "March" , "April" , "May" , "June" , "July" , "August" , "September" , "October" , "November" , "December"],
            y=["vul-report" , "resk" , "reports" , "web" , "scan" , "email" , "call" , "open-src"],
            size_max=50,  
            )

    if value == 'graph2':
        return px.bar(
            df,
            x=["January" , "February" , "March" , "April" , "May" , "June" , "July" , "August" , "September" , "October" , "November" , "December"],
            y=["vul-report" , "resk" , "reports" , "web" , "scan" , "email" , "call" , "open-src"],
            )
    
    else:
        return px.bar(
            df,
            x=["January" , "February" , "March" , "April" , "May" , "June" , "July" , "August" , "September" , "October" , "November" , "December"],
            y=["vul-report" , "resk" , "reports" , "web" , "scan" , "email" , "call" , "open-src"],
             barmode="group",
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

pic of the data:
[image]

dummy data :)

pic of the current result:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you transpose the `df`? Try setting `df=df.T` before you pass it to `px.bar`

Comment: @DerekO ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 12, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is 8

Comment: I think you have typos in your code. you set `x` to the list of months in  `graph1` but for `graph2` and `graph3`, you are setting `y` to the list of months (you need to reverse the x and y parameters)

Comment: @DerekO my bad sorry didn't change it before posting the code, I was trying to understand what is the default format so I changed the x and y, and it only made the bars in the y and values in the x (horizontal chart)

Comment: did transposing the df work after correcting for that typo?

Comment: ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 8, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is 12

Comment: let me get back to you on this